# select tables relationship

Tags: sql, select, relationship

I need help. I have 3 tables like this:

```
product
    * id
    - name

supplier
    * id
    - name
    - active

product_supplier
    * id_product
    * id_supplier
```

Is last table lists the product to the supplier.

What I need is to build a query that returns me only active suppliers and still are not related to specific product.

Thanks!!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with subquery as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM supplier
WHERE active = 'Y'
AND id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id_supplier
               FROM product_supplier)
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous, because if there's a NULL value for id_supplier, the NOT IN will always be false, and no rows at all are returned. To be safe, either add "WHERE id_supplier IS NOT NULL" to the sub-query, or, even better, use NOT EXISTS instead. Also, no use for DISTINCT in the sub-query.

Comment: Agreed but see OP has marked them as PK/FK in his question so it can't be null.

Answer (score 1):

This is your question:  "What I need is to build a query that returns me only active suppliers and still are not related to specific product."

You are looking for active suppliers that *don't* have a particular product.

```
select s.id
from product_supplier ps join
     supplier s
     on ps.id_supplier = s.id
where s.active = 1
group by s.id
having sum(case when ps.id_product = XX then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

You can can also do this with `not exists`:

```
select s.id
from supplier s
where s.active = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from product_supplier ps
                  where ps.id_supplier = s.id and
                        ps.id_product = XX
                 )
```

And, you can do this with a `left join`:

```
select s.*
from supplier s left join
     product_supplier ps
     on ps.id_supplier = s.id and ps.id_product = XX
where s.active = 1 and ps.id_supplier is null;
```

This seems like the most natural way to express this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much...It work with this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM supplier s
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM product_supplier ps
WHERE s.id = ps.id_supplier
AND ps.id_product =5
)
AND s.active =1
```